# How to handle network connectivity issues (Firebase FireStore)?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

For testing, I've turned off networking. I've got caching disabled:

```
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false // https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline -- done to help demonstrate async handling
```

I'm noticing that *error* is not set even though I see this in my logs:

> 2018-08-04 10:26:26.441529-0400 Behavior-based Notifications
>   prototype[52077:2250670] 5.4.1 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001]
>   Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 2 times.
>   Most recent error: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=2
>   "Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable
>   host) has occurred." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Network error
>   (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has
>   occurred.}  This typically indicates that your device does not have a
>   healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in
>   offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Here's relevant code snippet:

```
DBIFirebase.db.collection(URI).getDocuments() {
    (snapshot, error) in
    if tx < 1 {
        print("returned from Firebase TX when tx count is exhausted, dropping")
        return
    }

    if let error = error {
        // in either case, there was a previous error
        print("Firestore error loading data for app \(app) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
        callback(samples, Errors.firebaseError)
        tx = 0
        return
    }
```

error is always nil. documents are always empty.

---

#### edit:

Very near after that if let error, I use this to process the documents:

```
guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
    print("no documents for app \(app)")
    callback(samples, nil)
    tx = 0
    return
}

for document in documents {
```

I set a breakpoint. error is seen to be `nil`. stepping into this block skips over it (the *guard* block doesn't trigger, I'm talking about stepping into from a breakpoint at the *for* loop). If I turn networking on, it goes into it (not a swifty caching loops thing).

---

How would I distinguish between an empty but successful return and a network connectivity issue?

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain how you're observing that "documents are always empty"?

Comment: sure thing, thanks for looking

Comment: @DougStevenson anything come of this?